# What is a better association for array key name and file entry?

Tags: freepascal, overloading

Source:

```
  // write
  Path := 'Data/_prefixed' + dynarray1[v].Name;
  with XMLConfig1 do begin; 
      SetValue(Path  + '/RealName', dynarray1[v].Name);
  end;
  ..
  // read
  Path := 'Data/_prefixed' + listOfVars.Strings[v]; 
  with XMLConfig1 do begin;
     dynarray1[v].Name := GetValue(Path + '/RealName', '');
  end;
```

I think about writing simple macro like:

```
procedure getsetkey(Keyname,Var:string; var Value: **overloaded**; Direction: integer);
getset('Data/_prefixed'+Keyname, Var
```

but due to different return types it is still three (integer, string, boolean) similar functions (nothing like ?), or ever six function, if I throw out Direction argument and get a sets of `setkey` and `getkey`, or `key(overload: call set if 4-th parameter presents)`, (Value is *allowed to be empty*, so checking the value isn't the way to decide)

Any way to shorten number of functions and to associate dynarray1[v].Element_Name with a key that may be passed to GetValue()? Some kind of Reflection-like API to access key names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variants would be more logical. If you can get reflection/RTTI info (e.g. everything you want to save is a published property) that is also possible.

But IMHO for 3 variants of a 1 line function that is like shooting with a canon on a mosquito